# Flutter Release Apk Display black screen Issue on Startup

Tags: android, flutter

i have developed an flutter application and build a debug apk and it just works perfectly.
But when i generate a release apk and install it, then it will display as a black screen instead of my actual screen(Login Screen).

Comment: Is it stuck on the black screen or crashes?

Comment: yes only stuck on black screen. on start up it shows my login screen for 1 second and turns into black screen

Comment: Ok. Check if permissions such as Internet are specified in the Manifest file before generating the release apk. Check the flutter.dev [deployment](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest) once again to just verify.

Comment: ok, but actually i am generating release apk from the flutters android project in Android Studio, so does it cause any problem?

Comment: Didnt understand the question clearly but you mean to say you are following [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#how-do-i-build-a-release-from-within-android-studio) method right ?

Comment: yes, same steps

Comment: how did you solved it ?